# Unable to receive data from AJAX call [Flask]

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask, stripe-payments

**What I Am Trying To Do:** Receive data from AJAX to Flask. Eventually, I would like to send token data (Which will come from stripe) to the flask side

**The Problem:** I can't print any data to the console. So I'm assuming data is not being passed through.

I am unable to receive data from my Ajax call. I have been searching for some time now and I haven't found a fix. I've seen multiple different solutions for others but none of them worked for me. I'm am trying to implement a custom Stripe payment flow.

What I plan to do eventually is to pass in all the data I need (in the token) through the 'data' parameter in JSON format. Here are the different sides of code

### index.html

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'test_key',
  image: 'image_url',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/charge',
      data: {
        'token': '(data im trying to access/print in app.py)'
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(error);
      },
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json"
    });
  }
});
```

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json

@app.route('/charge', methods=['POST'])
def charge():

  # Grab token information
  token = request.form['token']

  # The line below never prints to console
  print(token)

  # This test print statement below never prints to console
  print("This print statement never runs")
```

Nothing prints to the console. I've wasted so much time on this so any leads or pointers would be **greatly** appreciated!

**UPDATES**

I did some updates suggested by **@Daniel Roseman** but nothing at all prints to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

In javascript:

```
var data = {token: token}
$.ajax({
    url: '/charge',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(error);
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
});
```

In controller [charge method]:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, jsonify

@app.route('/charge', methods=['POST'])
def charge():
    # Grab token information
    token = request.json['token']

    # This is the expected token from json
    print(token)

    # This test print statement below now prints to console
    print("This print statement now runs surely")

    # return JSON
    return jsonify(
        code=0,
        msg="Success"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not posting JSON.

Instead of accessing `request.get_json()`, you can just access the individual elements from the [`request.form`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#the-request-object) dictionary. In this case:

```
token = request.form['token']
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I took your suggestions and now I don't get the error in the console anymore! The bad side is that nothing prints to the console now, not even test print statements. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?